# How to make both bidirectional hiberbate entities serialized

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpql, bidirectional

I have 2 Entities:

```
public class Restaurant {
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "restaurant")
  private Set<Vote> votes;
}
```

and

```
public class Vote {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false)
  private Restaurant restaurant;
}
```

if I try to get both of them like that

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Restaurant r JOIN FETCH r.vote ")
```

I get Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON. So I managed to find a way to handle that:

```
public class Restaurant {
  @JsonManagedReference
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "restaurant")
  private Set<Vote> votes;
}

public class Vote {
  @JsonBackReference
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false)
  private Restaurant restaurant;
}
```

Now I can get restaurant with votes like that?

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Restaurant r JOIN FETCH r.vote ")
```

But now I CAN'T GET Votes with restaurant

```
@Query("SELECT v FROM Vote v JOIN FETCH v.restaurant ")
```

because @JsonBackReference meant

```
private Restaurant restaurant;
```

wont be serialized. But i need both of this bidirectional relationship in my controllers. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For serialization of entities with bidirectional relationship use `@JsonIdentityInfo` and remove the `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference`. The property of the `@JsonIdentityInfo` refer to your entity `id` property used to identify entity.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Restaurant {

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Vote {
```

Comment: If you find this solution helpful , you can upvote it also