# Infinite Recursive Loop While Using OnetoMany and ManytoOne Mapping (Bidirectional)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

In My Spring Boot Rest Application,I have Three Model Classes

`User`,
  `Business`,
  `Review`

User.java

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "partner",fetch = 
 FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Business> business;
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="user")
private List<Review> reviews;
```

Business.java

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="business")
private List<Review> reviews;

    @JoinTable(name = "business_service",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "business_id_fk") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "serviceIdFk") })
        private List<ServiceVO> services = new ArrayList<ServiceVO>();
```

Review.java

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "businsessIdFk")
private Business business;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "addedBy", nullable = false)
private User user;
```

When i try to find a business with a business_id via Repository ,I get an infinite Recursive Json List.
   I have to find User with user_id but there also same thing happens.

Any help will be appreciated

NB : i have already Used JsonIgnore as mentioned in an answer.it gets me another jackson binding error

```
   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No 
   serializer found for class 
   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no 
   properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, 
   disable 
   SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: 
   com.ovoox.model.Business["services"]- 
  >org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]- 
   com.ovoox.model.ServiceVO$HibernateProxy$
   TOMK9CML["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
```

Comment: Do you use ObjectMapper instance while serializing?

Comment: @Eric  Please See the updated Question

Comment: @ustaad please use correct package class org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore

Comment: this will solve issue.

Comment: **spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false** , use this in your properties file.

Comment: @Eric yea it solved the exception but i am not getting the business object inside review object because of the jsonignore

Comment: Does this solution solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/61775775/4207306

Answer (score 0):

In this case, User is mapped with Review by one to many relationships & again Review is mapped with User by many to relationship. So whenever you retrieve User you get list of Reviews which in turn user, causing this to be a JSON infinite recursion. To get rid of this try below code:

In Review.java **POJO**

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "businsessIdFk")
private Business business;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "addedBy", nullable = false)
private User user;

@JsonIgnore
public Business getBusiness(){
    return business;
}

@JsonIgnore
public User getUser(){
    return user;
}
```

Use @JsonIgnore for removing this object to avoid recursion.

Comment: Already Tried  @JsonIgnore,But It gets me another error com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class

Comment: try org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore this class

Comment: can you share your whole class definition ?

Comment: Believe me there is something else, I have got this problem many times and solved it using JsonIgnore.